# On the sup-norm and the $L^\infty$-norm on the space of bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers. We denote by $\#$ the counting measure on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$.

It is well known that $L^\infty(\mathbb{N},\#)$ (this space is often written as $l^\infty$) becomes a Banach space with the norm $\|u\|_\infty=\sup\{a \in \mathbb{R} \mid \#(\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid |u_n|>a\})>0\}$, $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{N},\#)$. It holds for any $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{N},\#)$
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad \|u\|_\infty=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|u_n|.
\end{align*}
However the proof for (1) I know is roundabout. I use the relation
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{\infty}=\lim_{p \to \infty}\|u\|_p=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|u_n|,\quad u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{N},\#) \cap L^q(\mathbb{N},\#).
\end{align*}
Here $q\ge 1$ and $\|u\|_p$ denotes the $L^p$-norm of $u$.

Do you know a simpler proof? If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$
\alpha := \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |u_n|
$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$. By your definition of $\|u\|_\infty$ there is some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\|u\|_\infty - \epsilon < a \leq \|u\|_\infty
$$
and
$$
\#(\{n\in \mathbb{N} \mid |u_n|>a\}) >0.
$$
This implies that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you have that $|u_n|>a$ and thence $\alpha > a$. Thus
$$
\alpha > a > \|u\|_\infty - \epsilon
$$
and making $\epsilon \to 0$ we obtain that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\alpha \geq \|u\|_\infty.
\end{equation}

For the reverse inequality, take again $\epsilon > 0$, by the definition of $\alpha$ there is some $n$ such that
$$
\alpha - \epsilon < |u_n| \leq \alpha.
$$
This implies that
$$
\alpha - \epsilon \in \{a \in\mathbb{R} \mid \#(\{n\in\mathbb{N} \mid |u_n|>a\}) >0\}
$$
and as consequence, by definition of $\|u\|_\infty$, we have that
$$
\|u\|_\infty \geq \alpha - \epsilon.
$$
Making $\epsilon \to 0$ we have that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\|u\|_\infty \geq \alpha.
\end{equation}

Equations (1) and (2) prove the result.